# How to get data from array using Alamofire to display in CollectionCell?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, alamofire, uicollectionviewcell

I am creating an app which requires to pull data from API, the scenario is, I will get the `json` data below:

```
[
  {
    "chargeId": "33fbbbd0-2e33-11e9-a2cb-8a27ecbbcb73",
    "chargeDate": "2019-02-12T03:28:44.000",
    "vatRate": "NON-VAT",
    "taxRate": 0.1,
    "policyGroup": "Patient Participation",
    "itemDescription": "Ecg at er/icu df",
    "scdFlag": 0,
    "amounts": null,
    "scdDiscounts": 0,
    "othDiscounts": 4.54,
    "adjustment": 0,
    "pfBill": 222.46,
    "vatAmount": 0,
    "taxableAmount": 11.12,
    "merchantDiscount": 0,
    "creditedAmount": 211.3,
    "chargeAmount": null,
    "previousCredits": null
},
{
    "chargeId": "5a2cabc1-46c9-11e9-a2cf-863c7cdffd18",
    "chargeDate": "2019-03-15T10:24:21.000",
    "vatRate": "NON-VAT",
    "taxRate": 0.1,
    "policyGroup": "Patient Participation",
    "itemDescription": "Professional Fees",
    "scdFlag": 0,
    "amounts": null,
    "scdDiscounts": 0,
    "othDiscounts": 0,
    "adjustment": 0,
    "pfBill": 1000,
    "vatAmount": 0,
    "taxableAmount": 100,
    "merchantDiscount": 0,
    "creditedAmount": 900,
    "chargeAmount": null,
    "previousCredits": null
  }
 ]
```

I did pulled the data successfully by using the `Alamofire` code below:

```
    typealias getPatientDetailsPerPayoutTaskCompletion = (_ patientDetailsPerPayout: [PatientPayoutDetails]?, _ error: NetworkError?) -> Void

  static func getPatientDetailsPerPayout(periodId: Int, doctorNumber: String, parameterName: PatientParameter, hospitalNumber: String, completion: @escaping getPatientDetailsPerPayoutTaskCompletion) {


        guard let patientDetailsPerPayoutURL = URL(string: "\(Endpoint.Patient.patientPayoutDetails)?periodId=\(periodId)&doctorNumber=\(doctorNumber)\(parameterName.rawValue)\(hospitalNumber)") else {

            completion(nil, .invalidURL)
            return
        }

        let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
        sessionManager.session.getAllTasks { (tasks) in
            tasks.forEach({ $0.cancel() })
        }

        Alamofire.request(patientDetailsPerPayoutURL, method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in
            print(patientDetailsPerPayoutURL)
            guard HelperMethods.reachability(responseResult: response.result) else {
                completion(nil, .noNetwork)
                return
            }

            guard let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode else {
                completion(nil, .noStatusCode)
                return
            }

            switch(statusCode) {
            case 200:
                guard let jsonData = response.data else {
                    completion(nil, .invalidJSON)
                    return
                }

                let decoder = JSONDecoder()

                do {
                    let patientDetailsPayout = try decoder.decode([PatientPayoutDetails].self, from: jsonData)
                    completion(patientDetailsPayout, nil)
                } catch {
                    completion(nil, .invalidJSON)
                }

            case 400: completion(nil, .badRequest)
            case 404: completion(nil, .noRecordFound)
            default:
                print("**UNCAPTURED STATUS CODE FROM (getPatientDetailsPayout)\nSTATUS CODE: \(statusCode)")
                completion(nil, .uncapturedStatusCode)
            }
        }
```

The `JSON Data` will display in a `CollectionCell`, and user will tapped the `cell` to view the data under one `chargedId` but unfortunately, when I tapped the `cell` the all data are pulled instead of one part of the array only. The code below is what I used to pull just part of the array:

```
typealias getSelectedPatientItemDetailsTaskCompletion = (_ selectedpatient: PatientPaymentDetails?, _ error: NetworkError?) -> Void

static func getPatientItemDetails(periodId: Int, doctorNumber: String, parameterName: PatientParameter, hospitalNumber: String, chargeId: String, completion: @escaping getSelectedPatientItemDetailsTaskCompletion) {


    guard let patientDetailsPerPayoutURL = URL(string: "\(Endpoint.Patient.patientPayoutDetails)?periodId=\(periodId)&doctorNumber=\(doctorNumber)\(parameterName.rawValue)\(hospitalNumber)") else {

    completion(nil, .invalidURL)
    return
    }

    let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
    sessionManager.session.getAllTasks { (tasks) in
    tasks.forEach({ $0.cancel() })
    }

    Alamofire.request(patientDetailsPerPayoutURL, method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in
    print(patientDetailsPerPayoutURL)

    guard HelperMethods.reachability(responseResult: response.result) else {
    completion(nil, .noNetwork)
    return
    }

    guard let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode else {
    completion(nil, .noStatusCode)
    return
    }

    switch(statusCode) {
    case 200:
    guard let jsonData = response.data else {
   completion(nil, .invalidJSON)
    return
   }

   let decoder = JSONDecoder()

   do {
    let patientDetailsPayout = try decoder.decode(PatientPaymentDetails.self, from: jsonData)
   completion(patientDetailsPayout, nil)
   } catch {
  completion(nil, .invalidJSON)
   }

    case 400: completion(nil, .badRequest)
    case 404: completion(nil, .noRecordFound)
    default:
    print("**UNCAPTURED STATUS CODE FROM (getPatientDetailsPayout)\nSTATUS CODE: \(statusCode)")
    completion(nil, .uncapturedStatusCode)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Didselect Function to pull data**

```
switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
       self.selectedCardIndex = indexPath
       let selectedItem = selectedItemDescription.id
       getItemDetails(parameter: .searchByChargedId, from: selectedItem)
        let cardController = UserCardViewController.init(nibName: "UserCardViewController", bundle: nil)

        present(cardController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    default: break
        }
    }
```

**getItemDetails Function**

```
 func getItemDetails(parameter: PatientParameter, from: String) {

 APIService.PatientList.getPatientItemDetails(periodId: currentRemittance.periodId, doctorNumber: doctorNumber, parameterName: parameter, hospitalNumber: patient.hospitalNumber!, chargeId: from) { (getItem, error) in

        guard let pageItemDescription = getItem, error == nil else {
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            return
        }

        switch parameter {
        case .selectedByChargedID:
            if self.patientPayoutDetails == nil {
                self.selectedPatientItemDescription = pageItemDescription
            }else {
                self.patientPayoutDetails.append(contentsOf: pageItemDescription.chargedId)
            }

        default: break
        }
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

        }
}
```

Hope you can help me, sorry if I included almost all the code but I just want to show you the flow of my codes. Been working on it for almost 1 week. Thank you.

Comment: Some important parts of the code is missing for us to make logic of. In your didSelect code, we are missing most of the logic where you try to find the selected item for the selected row, you seem to set a `selectedCardIndex` but then proceed to use a `selectedItemDescription.id` but we do not see how this value is first set.

Comment: Also it would seem that both `getPatientDetailsPerPayout` and `getPatientItemDetails` are pulling from the exact same URL.

Comment: @ekscrypto  `selectedCardIndex` is from the `GarlandView pod 1` `open var selectedCardIndex: IndexPath = IndexPath()`

Answer (score 0):

Both of your functions `getPatientItemDetails` and `getPatientDetailsPerPayout` are retrieving data from the same URL:

```
guard let patientDetailsPerPayoutURL = URL(string: "\(Endpoint.Patient.patientPayoutDetails)?periodId=\(periodId)&doctorNumber=\(doctorNumber)\(parameterName.rawValue)\(hospitalNumber)") else {
```

You probably have different URL for different endpoints; verify the URL for both methods making sure you use the appropriate ones.

Comment: yes, its the same endpoint, Do I have to create separate endpoint so I could pull the data under one `chargedId`?

Comment: @Titus typically if you are attempting to retrieve details of a specific record sometimes, and a list of records other times, they would be provided by two different endpoints, or at least, a single endpoint receiving different parameters.